# When using Core Bluetooth, can two iPhones be both central and peripheral devices?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm new to Core Bluetooth.

Using this framework, can an iPhone 4S (running iOS 6.0.1) be a central device, with an iPhone 5 (running iOS 6.0.1) acting as a peripheral?

Comment: While this is a question involving hardware capabilities, it directly relates to the functionality of the Core Bluetooth framework, so I believe it is appropriate as a question here. I've reopened it as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible as the iPhone 4S has the required BTLE hardware. See the sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html) for guidance on how to configure the central and peripheral.

As you don't say what your problem is, note that there are size limits to the amount of data you can transfer in each 'packet'.

Comment: Thanks Wain. Got it solved by restarting xcode. I was going through that sample and did make that work. Also, would like to know if there any sample available which about sending the data central to the peripheral?

Comment: I haven't tried it but after you have connected to a peripheral you have the `writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:` method available.